# Heroku NameError: name 'application' is not defined flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to develop the back-end part of the application for my work at the institute. I have a main file `app.py` in which I'm importing `model.py` which is in the same folder as `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import sys
from model import *
```

But Heroku shows this error:

```
rez = model.get_notes()
2021-04-30T15:20:41.746547+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also here is my `Prosofile`:

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 app:app
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from model import *
```

Here, you import everything from `model`. Not `model` itself.

This means that `model` isn't defined when you call `model.get_notes()`.

- Instead, you can either call `get_notes()` without model
- or `import model` at the top instead.